# In RStudio: 'cannot open file' - but it's there

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a problem with trying to work with the 'diamonds' data in ggplot2 (this is while trying to work through the exercises in 'R for data science'). I have now reinstalled Rstudio (1.0.143) and R (3.4.0) on a 64 bit Windows 10 laptop, and have the same problem. So:

```
> library("tidyverse", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.4")
Loading tidyverse: ggplot2
Loading tidyverse: tibble
Loading tidyverse: tidyr
Loading tidyverse: readr
Loading tidyverse: purrr
Loading tidyverse: dplyr
Conflicts with tidy packages -------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------
filter(): dplyr, stats
lag():    dplyr, stats
> str(diamonds)
Error in str(diamonds) : 
  cannot open file '~/R/win-library/3.4/ggplot2/data/Rdata.rdb': No such file 
or directory
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In get(results[[i]], pos = which(search() == packages[[i]])) :
restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In str(diamonds) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

But the 'diamonds' data is there - if I use the same commands in R itself, on the same machine (library ... str(diamonds)) I get:

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':       53940 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ carat  : num  0.23 0.21 0.23 0.29 0.31 0.24 0.24 0.26 0.22 0.23 ...
 $ cut    : Ord.fact    ..... etc
```

Any ideas please? (first post on stackoverflow - would be grateful for any tips on etiquette).

Thank you, Chris

Comment: You mention you get the same result "in R itself". To be clear, the first attempt with the error message is when you're working in RStudio as opposed to the R GUI?

Comment: Why are you specifying the `lib.loc`? Does the same happen if  you just write `library(tidyverse)` instead?

Comment: Oh, and when you say "R itself" do you mean the console?

Comment: So yes, by 'R itself' i meant the console.

Comment: I loaded tidyverse by ticking the box in the list of packages shown within RStudio - this is how the library command had lib.loc in it.

Comment: While in RStudio, are you working in a project? What's in the global environment?

Comment: But, have now tried by just typing library(tidyverse), and RStudio then finds the diamonds file with no problems! Problem solved, thank you! It appears the problem is somehow caused by the lib.loc statement.